# Cannot start krita after installing it?

Tags: software-installation, krita

I have just installed krita. I have followed the following [guide](https://krita.org/download/krita-desktop/). But when I am trying to run it, I am getting the following error.

```
krita(8483)/kdeui (KIconLoader): Error: standard icon theme "oxygen" not found! 

krita(8483): No ksycoca4 database available! 

krita(8483)/kdecore (trader) KServiceTypeTrader::defaultOffers: KServiceTypeTrader: serviceType  "Calligra/Part"  not found 
krita(8483)/koffice (lib komain) KoDocumentEntry::queryByMimeType: Got no results with  "[X-KDE-NativeMimeType] == 'application/x-krita' or 'application/x-krita' in [X-KDE-ExtraNativeMimeTypes]" 
krita(8483): No ksycoca4 database available! 

krita(8483)/kdecore (trader) KServiceTypeTrader::defaultOffers: KServiceTypeTrader: serviceType  "Calligra/Part"  not found 
krita(8483): No ksycoca4 database available! 

krita(8483)/koffice (lib komain): Unknown Calligra MimeType  "application/x-krita" . 

krita(8483)/koffice (lib komain): Check your installation (for instance, run 'kde4-config --path mime' and check the result). 

krita(8483)/koffice (lib komain): "krita" part.desktop not found.
```

What have I done wrong. What should I do now?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Found the solution here:
[Okular crashes Ubuntu 14.04](https://askubuntu.com/questions/529907/okular-crashes-ubuntu-14-04)

Basically:

```
sudo apt-get install kdelibs-bin kdelibs5-data kdelibs5-plugins kdelibs-bin kdelibs5-data kdelibs5-plugins oxygen-icon-theme
```